# Bluetooth Speaker issue

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I have a JBL GO bluetooth speaker, which is kinda cheeky with Ubuntu.

Everytime when I connect it i can only listen to HSP/HFP mode, which is the bad quality, and I got to disconnect it several times, even remove it from Bluetooth connected devices list, and add it again, to select A2DP mode, which is the greater quality. Sometimes it won't select the connected device. 
What can I do? And for the record, I have Pulse Audio installed if this will help

Comment: See if http://askubuntu.com/a/889765/300665 helps at all

Comment: @Jeremy31 it doesn't help